# Save a selection from an UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, saving-data

So I have a UIDatePicker in Xcode. I need a way so that the UIdatePicker is saved automatically. So that the next time that user opens the app the UIDatePicker displays the same date that was inputed before he closed it last time. Here is some of my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var BirthdayPicker: UIDatePicker!
...
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //__________________________________________________________________________
    // This makes sure the user doesnt use a date after the current date
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.year = -300

    let minDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())

    components.year = 0
    components.day = 0
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0
    let maxDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())

    BirthdayPicker.minimumDate = minDate
    BirthdayPicker.maximumDate = maxDate
    //____________________________________
```

So whenever I open my app I get todays date. here's the screenshot [This is the todays date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeBsQ.png)

But what I really want when I open the app is

[This is a random date that I just set it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok7c1.png)

If you want me to be more specific or have any questions for me just leave a comment. I'm also not really sure of my code is useful but it’s something. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` has property `date` which represents current `Date` selected in date picker. You goal should be saving this date somewhere. `UserDefaults` should be enough for this case.

Start with creating `IBAction` for your date picker for event `.valueChanged` and when value is changed, save current date of your picker to `UserDefaults.standard` with key `"BirthdayDate"`

```
@IBAction func datePickerChangedValue(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "BirthdayDate")
}
```

then in `viewDidLoad` if there is already saved date in for key `BirthdayDate`, set current date of `BirthdayPicker`

```
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "BirthdayDate") as? Date {
    BirthdayPicker.date = date
}
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.year = -300
    let minDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date())
    BirthdayPicker.minimumDate = minDate
    BirthdayPicker.maximumDate = Date() // if `maxDate` is just current date, you can use `Date()`

    if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "BirthdayDate") as? Date {
        BirthdayPicker.date = date
    }
}

@IBAction func datePickerChangedValue(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.date, forKey: "BirthdayDate")
}
```